# Nginx starts to downloading index.php instead executing

Tags: 16.04, server, php, nginx

At my hosting control panel I set up my server api for server name (let it be `dev.domainname.com`).

`dev.domainname.com` config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        #listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/dev.domainname.com/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name dev.domainname.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

After I open dev.domainname.com brower receive a file called "download". Actually I checked that file - it is my `index.php` inside `/public`.

What's wrong?

Some additional info: I've installed SSL-certificate using `certbot`. `https://dev.domainname.com` isn't available too, I got `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

`sudo tail -n 20 /var/log/nginx/error.log` doesn't have any errors for the last hour.

`hosts` file contains one row:

`127.0.0.1 domainname domainname`

`sudo nginx -t` is also ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell nginx how to deal with php files.  I create a "macro" which is simply a file containing the following:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "display_errors=Off";
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

I then store that in `/etc/nginx/macros` and include it with

```
include macros/php;
```

Comment: Can I change php 7.2 to 7.1 to make it work? Or there is other way for 7.1?

Comment: Now I have 502 Bad Gateway...

Comment: Yes php 7.1 works the same way.  If you have bad gateway, are you sure you have php-fpm installed?